# Make a service to recognize gesture to bind an event on top of all other applications Android 4.X

Tags: android, layout, service, transparent, gesture

I try to do a service that will recognize the movement (+ longclick move up) to associate an event. 
However, I need this service also works when another application is launched.

At the moment I create a service that gives me a transparent LinearLayout. 
I can well recover movement, BUT I can not use the current application below. 
Can not click through the layout. I wish, however, that this is possible and that my service detects this movement only.

EX: on Android kitkatt there now has a fullscreen mode and during a slide back down on  windowing with the appearance of the taskbar, and the application below have not impacted.

Have you any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish, however, that this is possible and that my service detects this movement only.

That is not possible from an SDK app on Android 4.0+. Either you receive the touch events or the underlying app receives the touch events, not both. Otherwise, this would represent a security flaw known as tapjacking.

Comment: Ok, so i think you can probably help me. My aim it's to make a service who recognize a longclick + drag to launch an event.It must work on every applications and home.
I can't believe there's no solutions !! Thanks in advance @CommonsWare :)

Comment: @ColombetJosselyn: The apps that do this sort of thing do so from a small "hot spot" (e.g., a corner or edge) so as not to interfere with apps. You could try resizing your invisible view once your long-click time threshold is reached, and see if you can then capture the full drag. IOW, consider the long-click to be the trigger to activate the functionality of your app, then use the drag either as confirmation or to choose a particular event (e.g., based on drag direction). You would then resize the view to its small state. I have no idea if this would work, though.

Comment: thanks a lot, i accept your answer BUT if i need your help , can i tweet you ? :)